# Using Bluetooth speaker with wireless mouse dongle

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth, speakers, dongle

I just bought a Bluetooth speaker. It works fine with my smartphone and I want a way to also use it with my desktop PC.

I have a dongle for my Microsoft mouse. Will these dongles serve as Bluetooth gateway for any other devices? Can the dongle be used to pair my Bluetooth speaker with my pc?

Comment: It will most likely not work but why not try, instead of asking here without providing any information at all about the mouse or dongle or speaker.

Comment: I surely have tried, and it didn't work for me, that's why I'm asking here to see if it's possible. And I have provided the information I thought would be needed. I don't get why some users do bullying the questioners if they don't have any experience with the problem.

Comment: Your question does *not* indicate that you have already tried this. You have also not mentioned any makes/models so we are supposed to guess apparently according to you. It's not bullying; it's simply about you providing the requisite information that might help others help you. Get it? Learn to ask good questions and it will stand you in good stead elsewhere too.

Comment: seems a dead end debate, I'm just telling that if you don't have experience with the problem, why bothering to add negative comments? and also if you don't know the answer how can you judge if the information is enough or not!

Comment: Ok, my last comment here. Anyone who *can* help you will in all likelihood want to know the same information because answers relevant for certain hardware might not work for something else entirely. Your refusal to provide relevant details is strange and what you don't seem to understand is it doesn't help *you*. You want to act as if the information is some sort of state secret and asking for it is the wrong thing to do, be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dongles will not be able to connect to your Bluetooth speakers most likely unless they are Bluetooth mouse/keyboard.

If you are using a computer with a wireless card with Bluetooth on it you should be able to connect to the speakers, but if you do not have a wifi card that supports Bluetooth and you are not interested in upgrading your wifi card, you can buy a Bluetooth USB adapter such as this one [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007GFX0PY).

Comment: I used a bluetooth dongle and paired the speaker and it works. but the sound is terrible with pc , now I don't suggest using bluetooth speakers with desktop pcs.

Comment: okay but this should answer your question